# Spring boot 3 SSL properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I have to configure 2 way TLS in Spring boot 3. Previously in Spring boot 2, it was done by mentioning the value of the trust store and key store by setting these properties and configuring manually :

```
ssl.keystore=
ssl.keystore-password=
ssl.truststore=
ssl.truststore-password=
```

I the latest Spring boot 3 , I see that it can be configured by setting these properties alone and no configuration needed :

```
server.ssl.key-store=file:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
server.ssl.trust-store=file:truststore.p12
server.ssl.client-auth=want
```

The challenge is that I want to specify the contents of the .p12 file instead of specifying file path. May I know how it can be done?

Comment: *I want to specify the contents of the .p12 file instead of specifying file path* AFAIK it is not supported. You need to write the content in a file.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer:  With JKS, you must only specify Location.  With PEM, you can use either Location or Contents.

According to the following documentation, you can use Bundle way of setting SSL.

https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl

Example:

```
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      jks:
        server:
          key:
            alias: "server"
          keystore:
            location: "classpath:server.p12"
            password: "secret"
            type: "PKCS12"
      pem:
        client:
          truststore:
            certificate: "classpath:client.crt"
```

If you do choose a JKS store type, then you can only provide **(Location)** as you can see in the below code snippet.

```
    /**
     * Location of the resource containing the store content.
     */
    private String location;
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/47cac96dfe89b9b2e87b4b39d58e22a0e1b04c8d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/JksSslBundleProperties.java#L29

However if you do choose PEM, you are allowed to choose between **(Location)** or specifying the **(Contents)** instead.

```
    /**
     * Location or content of the certificate or certificate chain in PEM format.
     */
    private String certificate;

    /**
     * Location or content of the private key in PEM format.
     */
    private String privateKey;

    /**
     * Password used to decrypt an encrypted private key.
     */
    private String privateKeyPassword;
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/47cac96dfe89b9b2e87b4b39d58e22a0e1b04c8d/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/PemSslBundleProperties.java#L30

Comment: The latest Spring Boot documentation includes examples of configuring PEM certificates with both files and string content: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#features.ssl.pem

Comment: The Spring Boot team is considering a future enhancement that would allow the contents of a PKCS#12 certificate to be specified in a configuration file as a base64 encoded string. Follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36033 for updates on that.